# For loop prints 3 per link -Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a simple for-loop,
it runs but it prints each link 3 times. Why? (there are 3 'events' total in page)

Website I am trying to scrape from = https://www.aacr.org/get-involved/events/

Here is the code ->

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

productlinks = []
url='https://www.aacr.org/get-involved/events/'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
productlist=soup.find_all('article',class_='event')
for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
        productlinks.append(link['href'])
print(productlinks)

Any insights on how i can make it run 1 per link
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 1 url per link. it currently prints each link 3x

Comment: Okay...Check out my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last for loop to this:

```
for item in productlist:
    productlinks.append(item.a['href'])
```

Comment: Changed to this -

for item in productlist:
    productlinks = item.a['href']
        productlinks.append(link['href'])
print(productlinks)

It does not run?

Comment: Don't do all that. Remove the last for loop and just add these 2 lines to your code. The other lines are unnecessary. It should definitely work.

Comment: Yes how do i do that?

Also can you explain item.a['href'])  What is (dot. "A")?

Comment: Okay...It is actually simple. productlist contains all the article tags, so I am just looping through it. item is one of the elements within productlist, so it should be a single article tag. The article tag contains an a tag, so the a tag can simply be accessed using a dot. Then, ['href'] gets the href attribute of the a tag. So to summarize, item.a['href'] gets the href attribute of the a tag within the article tag.